# Apache Hostname RewriteRule Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently having an issue when using multiple RewriteRule's in my .htaccess file as per below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ourwebsite.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} server12345
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Each one works respectively when it's by itself. But as soon as I add both in, the second one won't work. The first one continues to work (no matter the order) but as soon as I try to access through the second rule, the server throws a 500 Internal Server Error.

Edit: if it helps I want to be able to access the site through both the domain and

```
http://server12345/subfolder/
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your rules are looping since condition is evaluating to true in all cases.

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ourwebsite.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} server12345
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```